# Change SVN to GIT with intelliJ

Tags: git, intellij-idea, svn

I downloaded a project which was managed by SVN.I cleared all the svn files however in IntelliJ it still shows "Subversion

[image]"

I already created a git repository and i can push changes with git commands. How can i change intelliJ so it uses git to manage the project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IntelliJ has the concept of [VCS roots](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/version-control.html) and your project's root folder is most likely marked as a Subversion root. Mark it as a git root instead in the `Project settings` -> `Version Control`.

Answer (score 4):

If everything else fails, you can try to edit the vcs.xml file, which is in the /.idea directory.

You should find that line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="VcsDirectoryMappings">
    <mapping directory="$PROJECT_DIR$" vcs="svn" />
  </component>
</project>
```

Replace "svn" by "Git":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="VcsDirectoryMappings">
    <mapping directory="$PROJECT_DIR$" vcs="Git" />
  </component>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

This way: VCS -> Import into Version Control -> Create Git Repository...
Then submit and push.